# producer consumer in golang

Tags: go, goroutine

Tried running the below code(producer & consumer) to understand goroutines and channel in golang (removed package and imports from the code snippet below):

```
var done = make(chan bool)
var msgs = make(chan int)

func produce() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            msgs <- i
    }
    fmt.Println("Before closing channel")
    close(msgs)
    fmt.Println("Before passing true to done")
    done <- true
}

func consume() {
    for {
            msg := <-msgs
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            fmt.Println("Consumer: ", msg)
    }
}

func main() {
    go produce()
    go consume()
    <-done
    fmt.Println("After calling DONE")
}
```

source code from: http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/producer-consumer

Below is the output when I run the code

```
Consumer:  0
Consumer:  1
Consumer:  2
Consumer:  3
Consumer:  4
Consumer:  5
Consumer:  6
Consumer:  7
Consumer:  8
Before closing channel
Before passing true to done
After calling DONE
```

Based on my understanding with goroutines and channel:
When we call produce() and consume() from main() using the go keyword, go runtime kicks of 2 goroutines(sort of threads in java world but not actual OS threads) and the main() goroutine comes and halts at "<-done".
Now inside produce() - the loop goes from 0 to 9 and inside the loop the msgs channel receives the int (0 to 9) 1 at a time which is being consumed in parallel by the consume(); however produce has no clue about it and it just keep looping for 0 to 9.

Question: Assuming my above understanding is correct. Once, the for loop is done why is the next printLine inside produce() not getting printed and also why is the msgs channel not getting closed? Why is the goroutine halting inside the produce() until the consumer consumes all the msgs?

Comment: The print statements in producer do get printed, and the msgs channel is closed immediately after the for loop exits. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Then why is it that in the output, the print statements - "Before closing channel" & "Before passing true to done" is printed after "Consumer:  8" i.e. after all the msgs are consumed?

Comment: Sending and receiving on an unbuffered channel is synchronous. The docs will probably help: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `msgs` channel is unbuffered. This means that for send to complete, there has to be a corresponding receive operation that can also complete. This provides a synchronization point between goroutines.

It's easy to see if you just add a few more print statements to your example

http://play.golang.org/p/diYQGN-iwE

```
func produce() {
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        fmt.Println("sending")
        msgs <- i
        fmt.Println("sent")
    }
    fmt.Println("Before closing channel")
    close(msgs)
    fmt.Println("Before passing true to done")
    done <- true
}

func consume() {
    for msg := range msgs {
        fmt.Println("Consumer: ", msg)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

    }
}
```

Output:

```
sending
Consumer:  0
sent
sending
Consumer:  1
sent
sending
Consumer:  2
sent
sending
Consumer:  3
sent
Before closing channel
Before passing true to done
After calling DONE
```

Comment: You can also see this by editing the original to have something like `var msgs = make(chan int, 99)`; a buffered channel with more than enough room. In that case main will likely exit before the consumer can consume anything/everything (the exact ordering is undefined).

Comment: I tired making the msgs channel as buffered. Added few print statements inside the consume(). I saw that every time I ran the code, "fmt.Println("After calling DONE")" was printed and even after that I could see print statements from inside the consume() function getting printed. Is it not correct that, whenever "<-done" receives the message in this case bool, it doesn't wait for any goroutine to complete? So why is it that in this case even though <-done was received and "After calling DONE" was printed I could still see consume() goroutine continuing?

Comment: @srock: The consumer is free to run up until main returns, so it's not impossible for it to print out some lines between `<-done` and the runtime shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var ch chan int
var ch1 chan struct{}

func main() {
    ch = make(chan int)
    ch1 = make(chan struct{})
    go producer()
    go consumer()
    <-ch1
    close(ch)
    close(ch1)
}

func consumer() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("number", <-ch)
    }
}
func producer() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    ch1 <- struct{}{}
}
```